# Изменение динамического двумерного массива

Tags: динамические-массивы, malloc

Мне нужно записать числа и они должны распределиться в массиве, по правилу: в первой строке расположить числа, оканчивающиеся на 0, во второй – на 1, в третьей на 2 и т.д
Помогите пожалуйста.

```
void Memory(int** a, int m, int  n){a = (int**)malloc(n * sizeof(int*));} //выделение памяти



void vvod(int** a, int m, int  n, int i, int j){

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)  // цикл по строкам
{
    // Выделение памяти под хранение строк
    a[i] = (int*)malloc(m * sizeof(int));
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
   }
```

Comment: `void Memory(int*** a, int m, int  n){*a =` ... менять надо указатели удалённые, а не локальные.

Answer (score 0):

Заводите массив `counts[n]` для счётчиков элементов в строках.
Для введённого числа x

```
row = x % 10;  
a[row][counts[row]++] = x;
```